# Slider is not aligning center, and paragraph is displaying overlapped with paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on bootstrap framework to make my website. I have created a slider having **id = flip_pix** and the very next one there is a paragraph div. In the slider there are 3 pictures. Issue which I am facing is that paragraph below the slider is overlapping. I want the paragraph div to be displayed right below the other slider div. I want this to be responsive.

Another one I want to make slider aligned middle of the parent div.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <div class="page-header">
          <h3>What you want <small> from me</small></h3>
     </div>
     <div id="flip_pix">
         <div class="active">
              <img src="img/slider-1.jpg" class="feature-img" alt="" width="100%"/>
         </div>
         <div>
              <img src="img/slider-2.jpg" class="feature-img" alt="" width="100%"/>
         </div>
         <div>
               <img src="img/slider-3.jpg" class="feature-img" alt="" width="100%"/>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div>
         <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </p>featureImg
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
        #flip_pix{
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        #flip_pix div{
            position: absolute; 
            z-index: 0;
        }
        #flip_pix div.prev{
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #flip_pix div.active{
            z-index: 2;
        }
    </style>
```

This is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add `height: ...px` to your `#flip_pix` style definition, because it's children have `position: absolute` and it doesn't know that height it should be.

Comment: yes i have added 250px height but this is not responsive.. There increases gap between slider and the paragraph div

Comment: You can try to add `position: relative` to `#flip_pix div.active` and remove `height: ...px` I advised you. It could help.

Comment: When I use position relative slider images are showing vertically... they are not really stacked by z-index

Comment: Are you using it only on `.active` elements? All other divs should be `position: absolute`.